# Jquery Smooth Scrolling Offset

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm making a one page site with sticky navigation on center top with width at about 1000px and height of about 20-25px, now i also included a smooth scroll function but my problem is whenever the page scrolls to it's active page, the title hid under the sticky nav, how do i get the offset of the bottom of the sticky navigation? Thanks.

This is the js code btw:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 800, 'easeInOutCirc');
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to keep your current code as it is, and add that off-set to the top of your website, is by adding the needed offset value after the .top, like so:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 20
    }, 800, 'easeInOutCirc');
});
```

Hope this answer is less complicated that the last one. :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.position()` method will give you the top and left offsets of the element in relation to the page. So you would just need to add the `.outerHeight()` of the sticky navigation to it's `.position().top` value.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/NUfaZ/1/

As you scroll down in the page, you'll see it's position get updated.

Comment: err sorry, but where should or how should i put that? i'm really really new to js. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer, both to include an example and also to correct an error: jQuery doesn't have a '.pos()' method -- it's called '.position()'.

Comment: Okay, now i got the outerHeight it's "20". But where do i put this "20" on my code? i tried it on scrollTop: $(target).offset({top:20}).top. but it didn't smooth scrolled. Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: You dont put the 20 in, outerHeight calcs it for you  your variable.  Look ast his example

Comment: Jim -- i'm having a hard time understanding the issue from your last comment. If you could create a jsFiddle, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry. But do you have an email? I'll send an image which i think will be much easier for me to explain. Sorry again.

Comment: Just upload the image somewhere and post a link

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://codepen.io/pikeshmn/pen/mMxEdZ

**Approach:** We get the height of fixed nav using *document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight*
And offset the scroll to this value.

```
var jump=function(e){  

e.preventDefault();                        //prevent "hard" jump
  var target = $(this).attr("href");       //get the target

      //perform animated scrolling
      $('html,body').animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight - 5  //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
        },1000,function()                  //scrolldelay: 1 seconds
        {
          location.hash = target;          //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
        });
      }

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('a[href*="#"]').bind("click", jump); //get all hrefs
    return false;
  });
```

P.S:

- It includes a nice 5 pixels difference between header and target
- Scroll effect is not hard, rather smooth; Smooth Scrolling